# Use progress bar as Image View src?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Is it possible to use the spinning progress bar as the src of an Image View in Android XML? Or if not via XML then doing it programmatically?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) for showing progress in your image view

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
img.setResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).
frameAnimation.start();
```

and for detail of frame animation android see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069719/3582473).